# REST endpoint of the list of groups a user has joined

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

A user, when admin, can create a group `POST /groups`

Any user can get a list of groups  `GET /groups`

How in REST should the endpoint be to get a list of groups of which one is a member?

Answer (score 0):

I would typically do something like `GET /groups?includingUser={userId}`.